# Adding a SVG filter in Chrome with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, svg

I tried to add a SVG filter to an image with JS. It works fine in Firefox.

I call the CSS method of jQuery to add an inline style which is manipulating an image:

```
colorFilter = 'url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'changeColor\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'' + config['red'] + ' 0 0 0 0 0 ' + config['green'] + ' 0 0 0 0 0 ' + config['blue'] + ' 0 0 0 0 0 ' + config['alpha'] + ' 0' + '\'/></filter></svg>#changeColor")';
```

I used percentage encoding for the escaped `'` already. Also I escaped it in a normal way. Both do not work in Chrome. Firefox is fine with both.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A normal <img>. Source is png or jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the SVG specification SVG filters work on SVG `<image>` elements. Firefox extended this to support [applying SVG filters to html](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2008/06/applying-svg-effects-to-html-content_04.html) `<img>` elements too but Chrome has not yet implemented this.

Comment: So i need to insert the image data into a canvas to change all colours smooth. i tried to avoid this with the idea above.

Comment: No, just use an SVG `<image>` element to display the image rather than a html `<img>` element.

Comment: You can also use a -webkit-filter to reference a filter defined within an SVG block. Works on edge Safari/Chrome.